# How can I make a loop keep going after the first condition returns true

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to write a method that will take a string, convert any letters to an int, and return all the converted ints to main, replacing the letters . I have if statements that convert all the letters to numbers, but I am having trouble making it work with a loop to convert all the letters instead of stopping after the first one. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
    public class PhoneNumberChecker
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Get the phone number
        System.out.print("Phone number to convert: ");
        String phoneNumber = input.nextLine();
        // Process each character in the phone number for display
        for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); ++i)
        {
            // Get the character
            char ch = phoneNumber.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter(ch))                         
                ch = (Character.toUpperCase(ch));               
            else
                System.out.print(ch);               
        }
        System.out.println(getNumber(phoneNumber));
        input.close();
        // end method

    }

    public static String getNumber(String phoneNumber)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); ++i)
        {
            char ch = phoneNumber.charAt(i);
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);

            if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'B' || ch == 'C')
                    return "2";         
                else if
                (ch == 'D' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'F')
                    return "3";
                else if
                (ch == 'G' || ch == 'H' || ch == 'I')
                    return "4";
                else if
                (ch == 'J' || ch == 'K' || ch == 'L')
                    return "5";
                else if
                (ch == 'M' || ch == 'N' || ch == 'O')
                    return "6";
                else if
                (ch == 'P' || ch == 'Q' || ch == 'R' || ch == 'S')
                    return "7";
                else if
                (ch == 'T' || ch == 'U' || ch == 'V')
                    return "8";
                else if
                (ch == 'W' || ch == 'X' || ch == 'Y' || ch == 'Z')
                    return "9";

        }
        return "";



}
}
```

Comment: The loop is stopping because `return` terminates the loop. You probably want to store the numbers somewhere and then return that rather than return individual numbers in a loop (which doesn't make sense because it will always terminate on the first iteration)

Comment: It sounds like you want to append the characters to a string and return the string after the loop, rather than return a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to append the string results to a string that will continue to grow as you iterate over the given phone number.

Create a String variable before your loop, then simply append to that string instead of returning the strings. Then once you're done iterating the phone number you can return the String.

```
public static String getNumber(String phoneNumber){

String convertedNum = "";
for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); ++i)
    char ch = phoneNumber.charAt(i);
    ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);

    if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'B' || ch == 'C')
        convertedNum  = convertedNum + "2"; //append to the string
    else if(ch == 'D' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'F')
        convertedNum  = convertedNum + "3";
    ...

return convertedNum; //then return it at the end
}
```

Comment: you're welcome! feel free to mark it as the answer in order to close the question. Good luck with the rest of your coding!

Answer (score 0):

You `return` from the method after the first character was handled. Let's modify your method:

```
public static String getNumber(String phoneNumber, int i)
{

    //for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); ++i)
    {
        char ch = phoneNumber.charAt(i);
        ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);

        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'B' || ch == 'C')
                return "2";         
            else if
            (ch == 'D' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'F')
                return "3";
            else if
            (ch == 'G' || ch == 'H' || ch == 'I')
                return "4";
            else if
            (ch == 'J' || ch == 'K' || ch == 'L')
                return "5";
            else if
            (ch == 'M' || ch == 'N' || ch == 'O')
                return "6";
            else if
            (ch == 'P' || ch == 'Q' || ch == 'R' || ch == 'S')
                return "7";
            else if
            (ch == 'T' || ch == 'U' || ch == 'V')
                return "8";
            else if
            (ch == 'W' || ch == 'X' || ch == 'Y' || ch == 'Z')
                return "9";

    }
    return "";
}
```

Note, that it has an `int` parameter and the cycle was commented out. Now, let's process a `String`:

```
public static function parseString(String input) {
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output += getNumber(input, i);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Note, that this is very simple to understand. The thing which makes it simple is the fact that a method is doing a single thing. `getNumber` gets a number from a `String` at a given index. `parseString` parses the `String` in the way your code suggested. Of course you can modify the initial `String` if that is the purpose, using `setChar`, but then the `getNumber` method should return the `char` representation of the digits.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use `String.relaceAll` instead of checking each char in a nested if-else. Example:

```
public static String getNumber(String phoneNumber){
    String result = phoneNumber.toUpperCase()
            .replaceAll("[A-C]", "2")
            .replaceAll("[D-F]", "3")
            .replaceAll("[G-I]", "4")
            .replaceAll("[J-L]", "5")
            .replaceAll("[M-O]", "6")
            .replaceAll("[P-S]", "7")
            .replaceAll("[T-V]", "8")
            .replaceAll("[X-Z]", "9");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `StringBuilder` as compared to `String` as it is preferable performance wise compared to String. The reason is String is `immutable`. So inside the loop the String object will be created again and again. Whereas `StringBuilder` is mutable so it is declared only once and then can be operated on by it's reference. You can use it as shown below:

```
public static String getNumber(String phoneNumber){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); ++i){
        char ch = phoneNumber.charAt(i);
        ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);

        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'B' || ch == 'C')
            sb.append("2"); 
        else if(ch == 'D' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'F')
            sb.append("2");

        else if(ch == 'G' || ch == 'H' || ch == 'I')
            sb.append("3");
        else if(ch == 'J' || ch == 'K' || ch == 'L')
            sb.append("4");
        else if(ch == 'M' || ch == 'N' || ch == 'O')
            sb.append("5");
     }

     return sb.toString(); 
}
```

You can read about performance of String vs StringBuilder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532499/6407858). `Pay attention to switch from concatination(+) to Builder`.